# Can Kubernetes Jobs can have args applied like Docker?

Tags: kubernetes

I know that I can override args when I `docker run myimage arg1`

Is there something like

```
kubectl apply -f myDeployment.yml arg1
```

My goal is to create a Kubernetes Job to create my database and fill it with content, when I initiate my App the first time:

rails-command.yml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: rails-command
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: api
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: rails-command-app
          image: myApp:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command: ['bundle', 'exec', 'rails']
          args: 
            - 'db:migrate'
```

Do I have to duplicate my Job to use `db:create`, `db:rollback` instead of `db:migrate`? or can I apply that file with **something like** this:

```
kubectl apply -f rails-command.yml db:rollback
kubectl apply -f rails-command.yml db:create
```

Comment: The linked question suggests using [Helm](https://helm.sh), which would let you fill in values like this using templating.  You could also make the Job's command be something like `bundle exec sh -c 'rake db:migrate && rake db:rollback && rake db:create'`, which would let you stuff this all into a single Job.

Comment: You should use initcontainer in your app container yaml. That way the db will be initialized first before starying your app container. You can get more information from here- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/